# How to index a row in a list

Tags: python, text

I have a list which i imported from a text file and im trying to iterate and check each line (row) in a for loop.

right now im stuck at a point that i need to read the next row in order to take an action, i tried to change it to Pandas data frame which wasnt really convenient.

Heres an example for my data which is a text file that i read from

```
Hello all my name is :
I am 30 years old
if i said hi : print hello
ELSE 
dont
```

and heres my code:

```
with open('source.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
if 'name' in line:
print('Name was mentioned')
elif 'age' in line :
 print('Age was mentioned')
elif 'hi' in line and 'ELSE' in line( *HERE i want to read the next line*)
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: there is also a function called `readline()`, which you can call on a file object. It will read one line from the file.

Comment: You can do this in DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('source.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        try:
            next_line = lines[index + 1] # try to access next.
        except IndexError:
            next_line = None # if no next row, set next_line to None

        print(line)
        print(next_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) so you have the index. Then just use `lines[index+1]` to get the next line. But be careful, if `index+1 >= len(lines)` this will cause a [IndexError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question very well, but if you are trying to iterate through a list and need the index of each iteration you can use the `enumerate` function, so your for loop would be :

```
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
```

for more information and examples you can check:

https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html

Answer (score 0):

Although I suspect that your actual requirement is more complex than this, merely accessing the next line can be achieved using zip to combine each line with the next one and get both in the loop:

```
with open('source.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line,nextLine in zip(lines,lines[1:]+[""]):
    if 'name' in line:
        print('Name was mentioned')
    elif 'age' in line :
        print('Age was mentioned')
    elif 'hi' in line and 'ELSE' in nextLine:
        print('hi was mentionned, with ELSE on next line')
```

output:

```
Name was mentioned
hi was mentionned, with ELSE on next line
```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't understand what you are truing to do but mayby this will help

```
for word in lines.split():
    if 'name' in word:
        print('Name was mentioned')
    elif 'age' in word :
        print('Age was mentioned')
```

note: this code will print 'Age was mentioned' only if the word -age- is there not the number , I mean it will not work if you said "I am 30 years old" because you didn't write the word -age-